# What Apple In-App Purchase Category and Purchase type to use

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have several iOS apps in the Apple App Store. I am wanting to add in-app purchase for one specific feature/service, but Apple's "Getting Started with In-App Purchase on iOS
and OS X" document in the developer's portal does not do an adequate job in describing which category and purchase type I should select.

The app itself checks availability for a reservation. **Example:** is there availability at restaurant A at 7:00pm. If not, get on a waiting list. The waiting list becomes active 72 hours (exactly) before the desired reservation time.

The in-app purchase I want to add is to is to add a feature/service to make an automatically listing for the waiting list at precisely the time it becomes active. This in-app purchase is a one-time event, and the user receives an email from the vendor that they are listed on the waiting list.

So would this in-app purchase be in the Service, Functionality, or Subscription category? And would the purchase type be Consumable (one-time event), or non-renewing subscription?

Comment: This sounds like a Consumable IAP.

Comment: Thanks. What category would you assign it for submission to Apple: Service, Functionality, or Subscription?

Comment: Functionality sounds most appropriate.